# Package for Generically Listening to Topics

Tags: ros, publisher, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get a list of topics while running a node.  For example, if a new message is published, is there a way to programmatically get the topic name posted (equivalent to running rostopic list in a terminal).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117336/package-for-generically-listening-to-topics/) by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2014-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used this to add topics of a certain type to a GUI selector:

```
ros::master::V_TopicInfo ti;
if(ros::master::getTopics(ti)) {
    for(ros::master::V_TopicInfo::iterator it = ti.begin(); it != ti.end(); it++) {
        if(it->datatype == _topicType)
            ui.topicsList->addItem(it->name.c_str());
    }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2014-01-14**:
Looks good to me.  I will try it and see if it works for my needs.  However, I may also need to do this in python.  I figured before I start digging I could ask if you knew of a solution for that as well?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-15**:
Yes and no: I don't have code, but there are python APIs that do exactly the same thing. If you can't find that easily in the rospy documentation, just see what rostopic list does.

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2014-02-11**:
So I setup and have the ability to get topics whether it be C++ or python.  I started looking further through the code to see if there was a way to listen for a new topic as a callback (similar to subscriber), versus a ROS loop, but did not see one.  Curious if I just missed it?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-11**:
You want something that tells you if a new topic has come up? I don't think that exists. So you'd probably need to keep polling.

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2014-02-15**:
That is what I assumed.  I just made a polling method to take care of it.  Thanks.